# Using .NET wrapper for COM object: Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, .net, com, activex, com-interop

I need some way to use ActiveX component in .NET (C#). I know it [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12840048/3602201) using dynamic object. But I would like to use typed wrapper (Runtime Callable Wrapper), generated by VS 2015 or TlbImp.exe. I tried use it this way:

```
var connector = new Connector();    // Connector is _interface_ with CoClass attribute applied. Yep, it works
connector.Login(connStr, flags);    // compile-time error
```

Connector object can be successfully created, but I can't call `Login` method because of compile-time error: `CS1955    Non-invocable member 'IConnector.Login[string, int]' cannot be used like a method.` Autogenerated wrapper looks like this (via IL Spy):

```
[Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"), TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FDual | TypeLibTypeFlags.FDispatchable)]
[ComImport]
public interface IConnector
{
    [DispId(201)]
    int Login
    {
        [DispId(201)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        get;
    }

    ...
}

[CoClass(typeof(ConnectorClass)), Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]
[ComImport]
public interface Connector : IConnector
{
    // nothing here
}

[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy"), TypeLibType(TypeLibTypeFlags.FCanCreate)]
[ComImport]
public class ConnectorClass : IConnector, Connector
{
    [DispId(201)]
    public virtual extern int Login
    {
        [DispId(201)]
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        get;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Note**: this ActiveX-component is successfully called from VBScript. Also I tried to generate .NET wrapper for other random COM-component in *the same way* and I *could* call methods. So why it doesn't work now?

Comment: Login is imported by TLBIMP as a property, while you seem to be expecting a method. The ActiveX's TLB may be invalid w/o preventing it to run successfully in other contexts). Do you have any IDL/ODL file we can take a look at? OR the binary or the TLB? Or is it a well known component?

Comment: @SimonMourier No, I have only dll. It is _not_ well-known component for internal use, from third-party company. Furthermore, it is in active development state. So, if it still can run from VBSript, but to be incorrect  the same time, it sounds believable.

Comment: What VBScript does is equivalent to what we do in .NET with the `dynamic` keyword. But when you import the TLB/DLL/OCX, it's a very different story. The first method can perfectly work while the second fails. If you can post the DLL somewhere we can have a look at it, otherwise, just use dynamic.

Comment: Yes, I'll try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096416/wrapping-a-com-object-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp. If I understand it right, using dynamic is more flexible in terms of possible version changes? So, it can be even better. Never worked with COM before.

Comment: Using ILSpy is surely the problem here.  C# does not support indexed properties other than the indexer.  So ILSpy surely mangled the declaration of the getter and dropped the two arguments on the floor.  The price of freeware tooling.  Use Tlbimp.exe instead, the Embed Interop Types feature makes it a no-brainer.  If you did use Tlbimp then use get_Login().

Comment: Not sure, what did you mean. I generated wrapper using Tlbimp.exe and inspected resulting dll using ILSpy. I don't understand how one of this tools can replace another.

Comment: If it works fine, you can perfectly stay with dynamic. dynamic was also created for making COM easier with .NET. You just don't have intellisense to assist you (because there is no TLB).